# Enable multi-currency feature

Tags: multi-currency, certification

I've found around the network the [quizlet](http://quizlet.com/) website with some flashcard for salesforce: very promising for my 401 certification.

You can find it here: http://quizlet.com/47646837/flashcards

But I'm stucking in this question:

**How do you enable the multi Currency Feature in Salesforce.com?**

1. Enable it from the Sidebar componenet of Setup
2. Enable it from the profiles
3. Enable it from going in to the Currency Tab
4. Enable it by raising a case with salesforce.com

I've searched in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_enable_multicurrency.htm&language=en_US) and I've found:

> In Setup, go to Company Profile | Company Information and click Edit.
>   That let me think about the right answer is 2.

BUT! The correct answer in Quizlet is: 4.

Am I looking in the wrong documentation page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is #4 - see SFDC Help [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_enable_multicurrency.htm&language=en_US)

> Contact Salesforce to request enablement. Be prepared to provide the
> following information.
>
> The organization ID (production or sandbox)
>
> Confirmation that you understand that your current currency locale will become the default currency stamp for current and future records (USD, EUR, GBP, and so on)
>
> Confirmation that you understand that multiple currencies can’t be disabled once enabled
>
> Confirmation that you are a system administrator authorized on behalf of your organization to request multi-currency enablement and
> that you consent to the lockout of this organization for a certain
> period of time, depending on your organization’s data usage volume